# the output from the MySQL and the Oracle SELECTS Hackerrank THE PADS

Tags: oracle

i try to solve the pads challenge in hackerrank :
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-pads/problem?isFullScreen=true

Mysql :

```
SELECT CONCAT(Name, '(', LEFT(Occupation,1), ')') FROM OCCUPATIONS 
ORDER BY Name asc;
SELECT CONCAT('There are a total of ', count(name), ' ', LOWER(occupation),'s.' )
FROM OCCUPATIONS
GROUP BY OCCUPATION
ORDER BY count(name);
```

Compiler

```
You have passed the sample test cases.
```

Your Output (stdout)

```
Aamina(D)
Ashley(P)
Belvet(P)
Britney(P)
Christeen(S)
Eve(A)
Jane(S)
Jennifer(A)
Jenny(S)
Julia(D)
Ketty(A)
Kristeen(S)
Maria(P)
Meera(P)
Naomi(P)
Priya(D)
Priyanka(P)
Samantha(A)
There are a total of 3 doctors.
There are a total of 4 actors.
There are a total of 4 singers.
There are a total of 7 professors.
```

Oracle :

```
SELECT Name || '(' || substr(Occupation,1,1) || ')' FROM OCCUPATIONS 
ORDER BY Name asc;
SELECT 'There are a total of ' || count(name) || ' ' || LOWER(occupation) || 's.'
FROM OCCUPATIONS
GROUP BY OCCUPATION
ORDER BY count(name);
```

Compiler Message

```
Wrong Answer
```

Your Output (stdout)

```
Aamina(D)
Ashley(P)
Belvet(P)
Britney(P)
Christeen(S)
Eve(A)
Jane(S)
Jennifer(A)
Jenny(S)
Julia(D)
Ketty(A)
Kristeen(S)
Maria(P)
Meera(P)
Naomi(P)
Priya(D)
Priyanka(P)
Samantha(A)
There are a total of 3 doctors.
There are a total of 4 singers.
There are a total of 4 actors.
There are a total of 7 professors.
```

When i use mysql work as expected output, but when i try Oracle they give me "wrong answer" but i see the output seem too similiar. can somebody expert in oracle explain the problem to me?

Comment: Edit your question to include the output from the MySQL and the Oracle SELECTS.  It's probably an extra blank or a character out of place.

Comment: can you tell me where extra blank is?

Comment: Not until you edit your question to include the output from the MySQL and the Oracle SELECTS **as text**.

Comment: okay sorry gilbert

Comment: @Rin You can see the difference if you compare the two; the outputs from the second query are in different orders and the Oracle solution does not match the required order (that the MySQL solution produces the correct solution is coincidence and not because your solution is correct).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation section of the problem states:

> The results of the second query are ascendingly ordered first by number of names corresponding to each profession (*2 <= 2 <= 3 <= 3*), and then alphabetically by profession (*doctor <= singer*, and *actor <= professor*).

In neither of the solutions do you guarantee to generate the results with the correct ordering.

I don't know why the MySQL solution is being marked as correct (given your edit, it appears that MySQL is randomly producing the input rows in the correct order even when you are not using the correct `ORDER BY` clause and the output happening to be correct is purely coincidence) but it is right that the Oracle solution is incorrect as the rows are not in the correct order.

Comment: do you mean it supose to be doctors, actors, singers, professors output in oracle? becasue singer and actor have same value but it need to be sort using asc method?

Comment: @Rin The counts should be ordered `3, 4, 4, 7` and then when the counts are the same the occupations should be ordered `actor, singer` (and not `singer, actor` as your current output).

Comment: GROUP BY OCCUPATION
ORDER BY count(name), occupation;
it give me pass to next challenge but i dont know it is right to do?

Comment: @Rin Yes, that is correct and you **should** need the same change for the MySQL solution (if you are not going to rely on coincidence to generate the expected order).

Comment: thanks for give the insight, bro

Answer (score -1):

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(NAME,CONCAT(CONCAT('(',SUBSTR(OCCUPATION,1,1)),')')) FROM OCCUPATIONS ORDER BY NAME;

SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT('There are a total of',CONCAT(' ',COUNT(OCCUPATION))),' '),LOWER(OCCUPATION)),'s.') FROM OCCUPATIONS GROUP BY OCCUPATION ORDER BY COUNT(OCCUPATION),OCCUPATION;
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**